# New Itunes connect : Submitting app for review

Tags: app-store-connect

I am trying to submit a new version of my existing app in itunes connect but I am having difficulties. So I uploaded my build like usual and upload done. I went into pre-release and saw the status processing. This was 12 hours ago, now though it has changed from processing to inactive. I ignored that and went and chose the build anyways and clicked on "Submit for Review"

I get an error saying **You must submit your builds using Xcode 5.1.1 or later, or Application Loader 2.9.1 or later. After you’ve submitted a build, select it in the Builds section below.**

But I did submit a build using Xcode 6 seed version. I also tried to upload the build again but I get an error saying that a buid already exists. I figured I will try to delete the build, from the pre-release tab and try to upload a new build but I cant find a way to do this.

Makes me think it has something to do with the **inactive** status of the build. Is anybody else having this issue?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I successfully submitted an app about 2 days ago....

Comment: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: Regardless, the question "*Is anybody else having the same issue?*" is probably the culprit for these non-answers.  If you *have* to ask that, then there may be something wrong with the post as a whole.  You should just be asking if someone has a solution.

Comment: @Jamal I dont think my question is a "Customer service" question (refering to your link). iTunes Connect in practicality is a developer tool like IDEs are a developer tool and if SO users can help each other with IDE tools then iTunes Connect should be fair game. The new Itunes Connect is different and very new which might explain the non-answers, it's because they dont know the answers. I do get your point but I feel the line between valid/invalid SO question is a blur and in my humble opinion my question is slightly towards the valid territory.

Comment: Enable TestFlight Beta Testing, then your app status goes to 'Invite Testers'. then try submit again. Select options with radio buttons. Click Submit. Loading freezes at this screen.

Comment: Just some FYI.  I just added a build while it's status said inactive and it worked.  Looks like everybody's mileage may vary.

Comment: You can't use Xcode beta versions to submit applications. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Okay So I was able to submit my app for review. I guess you cannot wait for too long after you submit your build. I have no proof of this but I think if your build is inactive, you cannot use that build to submit an app. Here is what I did to solve my issue

1. In xcode I changed the build version, not the app version,
2. Archive and validate
3. Submit
4. While the build was still "Processing", I went back to my apps new version page on iTunes Connect
5. Choose the new build and submit for review.

Dont let the build become inactive.

Good luck

Comment: Thank you. This worked. I think one has to be quite quick otherwise the status goes to inactive. My first upload was inactive and I had the error. Seems to me the process is somewhat daft.

Comment: @nupac Question out of curiosity.. what does inactive build mean? I don't think so this issue was ever before the new itunes connect. I am facing exact same issue, so want to know about it. Thanks.

Comment: Worked for us too - no indication the build was stale.

Comment: @iAnum I have no idea what inactive means, researched for a long time and then gave up.

Comment: I think when it is in the prerelease we have to wait for it to finish processing before we may choose it as a build.  Seems slower than how they used to do it.

Comment: You guys rock .. can you shed any light on this one ... http://stackoverflow.com/q/26143661/294884

Comment: After submitting my app via Xcode, I simply logged out of iTunes Connect and logged back in. This worked for me.

Comment: thank you it work for me

Answer (score 14):

I was having the same issue.  I followed the guy above's advice.  Here's exactly what I did to get it to work:

1. In iTunes Connect, remove the current build.
2. In Xcode, change the build (not version) number to something else.  I just picked "3".
3. In Xcode, go to Product -> Archive
   Note: If this is greyed out, ensure that you select "iOS Device" instead of a different simulator or connected hardware for testing
4. In the Organizer - Archives window, click Validate, then click Distribute
5. In the Organizer - Archives window, delete your previously submitted archive
6. Go back to iTunes Connect, refresh, and select the new build with the updated version number

Comment: hah.  I know that feeling of wanting to comment and not being allowed.  Have a point.

Comment: Note: "build" in step 2 is referring to CFBundleVersion.

Comment: Pity this post is off topic because we are all having this problem and we would like to see if there is a solution/fix available.

Comment: Finally someone explains exactly how to do this. It's not obvious nor is it explained anywhere by apple in any help or documentation. This is the answer on how to submit your app to iTunes Connect. Not the one marked as the answer above.