# iTunesConnect - build in 'prerelease' but not in 'versions'

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

When I enter my app in iTunesConnect I can see it listed under Prerelease:

[image: Prerelease]

However the '?' sign isn't working. I don't see it under Versions, even though 2 previous versions are in ready for sale status or prepare for submission. Does it mean my build is invalid or something is wrong with it?

Yesterday it was on 'validating' status. Today it is normal, so I suppose it should be visible in versions too? I want to submit it to the AppStore.

-- question value as not programming topic --

Because it isn't strict programming question and ppl may want to vote to close it, looking at the https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic I think that is valid because of these points:

- software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
- a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

The question seems similar to [SOF question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25819206/new-itunes-connect-submitting-app-for-review), but I didn't get any errors and the solutions didn't work for me.

-- edit --
Screenshot of Versions tab, where version 1.27.0 is NOT visible:

[image: Versions]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please go to `Versions` tab, scroll down to `Version` section and change it to your new version eg. `1.27.0` as you've said. Then remove previous build and add a new one like @FabioCardoso said. That's all. Should help :-)

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

> Choosing a Build
>
> You can upload any number of builds for your app, and they will remain
>   in Prerelease on the App Details page. (See Viewing Builds.) When you
>   submit the app for App Review, only one build can be associated with
>   the App Store version of the app you want to submit. The build, called
>   the current build, is the one that will be submitted for App Review.
>
> To choose a build to be the current build, follow these steps:
>
> Open the App Details page for the app, as described in To open the App Details page for an app.
>
> On Versions, scroll down to the Build section.
>
> Click the plus sign to select a build. The plus sign appears only if you have uploaded builds and have not yet not selected a current
>   build. If you have already selected a build, you can remove it if you
>   want to select a new one. See Removing the Current Build.

You can see more [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingTheApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH33-SW9)

[image]

EDIT:

> Open the App Details page for the app, as described in To open the App
>   Details page for an app.
>
> On Versions, scroll down to the Build section.
>
> Click the plus sign to select a build. The plus sign appears only if
>   you have uploaded builds and have not yet not selected a current
>   build. If you have already selected a build, you can remove it if you
>   want to select a new one. See Removing the Current Build.

[image]

You have to select the build to submit [try it](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingTheApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH33-SW9)

Comment: If I understand it well, I should have version 1.27.0 in Versions. But I don't and that is weird. The question is now updated with a screenshot from Versions tab.

Comment: I edited my post. I think you have uploaded the 1.25.5 version without submit it for review, then you added the 1.27.0. Now you have to pick up the 1.27.0 version to submit it for review. Try it with the url I posted in the edited post.

Comment: But it will have the description as version 1.25.5 not 1.27.0 while it has to be number 1.27.0 or higher. Please do note that you select a build for specified version and I dont want to upload build with version number 1.25.5 but 1.27.0 even if it will be the same build in both cases.

Comment: And yes, as you've said, I have uploaded version 1.25.3, waited for review and published it to the appstore. Then I've added version 1.25.5 and didn't even push it to review (however it has build assigned). Now I'm adding version 1.27.0 and I want to push it to review and to the AppStore.